# Gradle ear is putting JAR instead of WAR

Tags: war, gradle, ear

I'm trying to build an **ear** using Gradle.
I've my project tree like:

```
/project
|
|--> /web-application
|    |
|    |--> /src (stuff of web app)
|    |
|    |--> build.gradle
|
|--> build-gradle
|--> settings.gradle
```

I'm trying to generate the ear using the **ear plugin**, but when I do `gradle assemble` I have the **war** created under the *build* directory of the *web-application*, but inside the generated **ear** I have a **jar** of the web application.
The gradle configuration files are very simple, here they are:

*project/build.gradle*

```
apply plugin: 'ear'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    deploy project(':web-application')
    earlib group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.15', ext: 'jar'
}
```

*project/web-application/build.gradle*

```
apply plugin: 'war'

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.15', ext: 'jar'
}
```

What I did wrong?

I notice that also the bundled samples for the war plugin, have the same problem...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 33, accepted):

SOLVED!

It needs to configure the WAR module inside the EAR project as:

```
dependencies {
    deploy project(path:':web-application', configuration:'archives')
    earlib group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.15', ext: 'jar'
}
```

Comment: Are there Any reference in the documentation?

Comment: I don't remember where I take that solution, and the documentation is a bit confusing about it...

Comment: Configuration doc: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid specifying a configuration for each *deploy* dependency using something like this:

```gradle
allprojects {
  plugins.withType(WarPlugin) {
    // Set default configuration as WAR archive if WAR plugin is used
    configurations {
      'default' {
        extendsFrom = [archives]
      }
    }
  }
}

...

dependencies {
  deploy project(':web-application')
}
```